# Picking a random json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I've got json data.

```
[
["Mango","M"],
["Lychee","L"],
["Pineapple","P"],
["Banana","B"]
]
```

I need to be able to pick an Array item randomly (e.g. `["Pineapple","P"]`). How can I do a random pick?

```
var alphabetNum = "";
$.ajax (
   { 
    url:"getalphabet.json"
   }).done(function(data) {
        alphabetNum = data;
});
```

Comment: 1) You have array 2) Array is integer indexed 3) produce random number [0, length) 4) alphabetNum[i]

Comment: data is the array you want pick randomly from?

Comment: That is not a JSON object.

Comment: @IfTrue it is actually a valid JSON (page 2 http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)

Comment: @Audrey I wasn't saying it was not valid JSON, I said it wasn't a JSON "object"  which the original post said it was. I just wanted to make sure in case OP did not know there is a difference that they can then go out and learn the difference between an array and an object. You can see the history before it was edited by clicking "edited [time past] ago" in the OP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just take `Math.random()` and the length of the array as factor.

```js
var array = [
    ["Mango","M"],
    ["Lychee","L"],
    ["Pineapple","P"],
    ["Banana","B"]
];
var randomItem = array[Math.random() * array.length | 0];

// take only the element with index 0
alert(randomItem[0]);
```

Comment: Looks good. Thanks :). Can you please explain the `| 0` in the last line?

Comment: short: a short form for `Math.floor()`. long: it forces the value to integer and applys a bit wise or with 0.

Comment: this `| 0` is not best idea, you just save few characters severing readability, there is no good reason for such gotchas, `Math.floor` is explicit and clear for everyone.

Comment: a long time ago i was thinking (an it was teached to me), that short cuts are evil, in sense of readability. now, i think the features of the language should used where ever it makes sense. i do not think, that unusual solutions should be avoided, because of somebody my not be able to gather information about the feature (quickly). as long as there are no side effects, and i can not spot some here, i go with that.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification Nina. Also with your solution how would I fetch the first value form this random pick? e.g. `Pineapple`